# Python - Do things to elements in a list using multithreading

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I want to do something to a element in a same list by using multithreading in Python. For example, download 3 files in a list at the same time.

Here's my code:

```
import threading
import time

thread_count = 3
l = [x for x in range(0, 10)]
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

def do_sth(x):
    print('%s\n' % x)
    time.sleep(1)

def worker():
    for x in l:
        l.remove(x)
        do_sth(x)

threads = []

for x in range(0, thread_count):
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
    threads.append(t)

for t in threads:
    t.start()
    print('Started: %s' % t)
```

But in the output there's always something disappear:

```
Started: <Thread(Thread-6, started 5924)>
0
1
Started: <Thread(Thread-7, started 2860)>
2
Started: <Thread(Thread-8, started 15648)>
4
5
6
8
9
```

Comment: Python lists are not thread safe. You should use a [Queue](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/queue.html).

Comment: do you hope to get a performance boost with the help of `multithreading`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lists are not threadsafe (meaning there are concurrency issues if you have multiple threads/processes using a single list). Use a [Queue](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/queue.html) instead. Here is the example from the docs adapted to your use case:

```
import threading
import time
import queue


q = queue.Queue()


def worker():
    while True:
        x = q.get()
        if x is None:
            break
        do_sth(x)
        q.task_done()


def do_sth(x):
    print(x)
    time.sleep(1)


threads = []
thread_count = 3

for x in range(0, thread_count):
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
    print('Started: %s' % t)

for x in range(0, 10):
    q.put(x)

# block until all tasks are done
q.join()

# stop workers
for _ in threads:
    q.put(None)

for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

Comment: This provides an alternative, not explaining **why** the particular behaviour is expected in list

Comment: @IshanSrivastava You mean explanation other than "Lists are not threadsafe (meaning there are concurrency issues if you have multiple threads/processes using a single list)"?

Comment: yes, alternatives are always welcome and to a fellow who just wants to make his code work, this is the best answer but for those hungry to know the insides, please atleast put some links over here for proper explanations of the incorrect working of the lists